# How can we transfer ethereum to contract which is deployed on polygon mainnet

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, polygon

So, suppose i designed a lottery contract which need 2 ethers to participate in lottery. Now because polygon has low gas fee i decided to deploy contract on polygon mainnet. But now im little bit confuse that if i deployed contract on polygon mainnet then how can i tranfer ether to that contract as it is on polygon mainnet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do it directly since the chains are different and use different native coins. The best you can do is to use WETH tokens, which will represent ETH on the Polygon chain.